# URL parse without String split

Tags: java, string, parsing, url

Java has cool URL parser

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class ParseURL {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    URL aURL = new URL("http://example.com:80/docs/books/tutorial"
                       + "/index.html?name=networking#DOWNLOADING");

    System.out.println("path = " + aURL.getPath());
}
}
```

Here is the output displayed by the program:

```
path = /docs/books/tutorial/index.html
```

I would like to take only this part : `docs/books/tutorial` (or `/docs/books/tutorial/`) Guessing don`t use string split, I am looking for other better resolution for this task.

Thank you in advance

Comment: You can always write a custom method to get the substring of path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few ways. One of them is using `URI#resolve(".")` where `.` represents *current directory*. So your code can look like:

```
URI uri = new URI("http://example.com:80/docs/books/tutorial"
        + "/index.html?name=networking#DOWNLOADING");
System.out.println(uri.resolve(".").getPath());
```

Output: `/docs/books/tutorial/`

---

Other way could involve file system and classes which handle it like `File` or its improved version introduced in Java 7 `Path` (and its utility class `Paths`).
These classes should allow you to parse `path`

```
/docs/books/tutorial/index.html
```

and get its parent location `/docs/books/tutorial`.

```
URL aURL = new URL("http://example.com:80/docs/books/tutorial"
        + "/index.html?name=networking#DOWNLOADING");

String path = aURL.getPath();
String parent = Paths.get(path).getParent().toString();

System.out.println(parent);// \docs\books\tutorial
```

(little warning: depending on your OS you may get path separated with `\` instead of `/`)

Answer (score 2):

```
String path = "/docs/books/tutorial/index.html";
path = path.substring(1, path.lastIndexOf("/"));
```

gives `docs/books/tutorial`

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with a File Object, rather than split your String:

Working example:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.net.URL;

public class ParseURL {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        URL aURL = new URL("http://example.com:80/docs/books/tutorial"
                           + "/index.html?name=networking#DOWNLOADING");

        System.out.println("path = " + aURL.getPath());

        File file = new File(aURL.getPath());

        System.out.println("pathOnly = " + file.getParent());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
path = /docs/books/tutorial/index.html
pathOnly = /docs/books/tutorial
```

Answer (score 1):

Take this as a example:

```
public static String getCustomPath() {
    String path = "/docs/books/tutorial/index.html";
    String customPath = path.substring(0, path.indexOf("index.html"));
    return customPath;
}
```